# Sentry delete issues (logs)

Tags: django, database, docker-compose, sentry

I'm running [Self-Hosted](https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/) Sentry 21.6.1 on-premise with `docker-compose up -d` and Django database is getting full very fast because of large number of collected issues. 3,218,732 Total Errors in 8 days.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       504G  130G  349G  28% /
```

How can I delete old issues (let's say older than 30 days) from the database or set new issues to overwrite the old ones once the disk is full? Or is there a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://dev.to/nixon1333/clean-sentry-database-on-premise-28b).

In the Sentry Docker directory, run:
`docker-compose exec worker bash`

After that from the worker bash run:
`sentry cleanup --days 15`

This will clean up all the events' data before 15 days.
This took around 5 hours to complete for 500 GB of data.
After cleaning, more than half of the data was deleted.

After this, inside the database run:

`docker-compose exec postgres bash`

`psql -U postgres`

`\c postgres`

`VACUUM FULL;`

This will lock database tables until the full vacuum operation is done!
Thanks again to the original post for this solution.

UPDATE: 2 weeks since cleaning I received around 5,000,000 errors and the size of the disk is still around 250 GB as was on the day of cleaning. It looks like the workers are doing real cleanups now.

Comment: I am running 21.7.0 and I had to use  ```docker exec -it sentry_onpremise_worker_1 bash``` to get into the worker container.

Comment: If you can't see the worker, run this command: `docker-compose run worker`.
This will bring up the worker. Then, exec into the newly created container.